# Extracting raster values to point feature class failing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, elevation, feature-class, mosaic-dataset

I need to extract values to point features from Mosaic dataset made out of  DEMs (Whole world SRTM) . My feature class has 18,000,00 points.

When I ran the below tools, only <20K points receive elevation values ,rest all are null though DEM at those location is not null.

**Spatial Analyst**

- Extract Values to Points
- Extract Multi Values to Points

**3D Analyst**

- Add Surface Information

Per suggestions in https://community.esri.com/  , I ensured below. None seems to work .

1. CRS of DEM and Feature Class is same
2. Do not open the fc and moasic  in ArcMap
3. Use Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst tools in Catalog
4. Put FC and Mosaic Dataset in a common Geodatabase
5. Run using ArcPy

Often I see claims of of this tool working after a relevant patch to 10.1 . I am using latest version 10.6 and seems to have no solution to this problem.

My production system is built on ArcMap so using ArcGIS Pro is not an option for me.

**How the tool is executed ?**

Tool Boxes > System Tool Boxes > Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > Extract Values to Points

```
Input point features --> D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\points
Input raster  --> D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\SRTM3
Output point features --> D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\points_elev
```

**Environment of the ArcMap**

```
OS : Windows 10
Virtual Technology : None
Webserver: None (using only desktop)
Service Pack: None
DBMS : File geodatabase (for storing Mosaic  dataset and feature class)
Virtual Technology : None
DBMS OS: Windows 10
DBMS Version: File Geodatabase
```

**ArcPy Script**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"in_memory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

# Set local variables
inPointFeatures = "D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\points"
inRaster = "D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\SRTM3"
outPointFeatures = "D:\Data\Terrain.gdb\points_elev"

# Execute ExtractValuesToPoints
ExtractValuesToPoints(inPointFeatures, inRaster, outPointFeatures,
                      "INTERPOLATE", "VALUE_ONLY")
```

**What happens with subset of points ?**

- When we experimented with subset say - 600 points or 20,000 points - the same issue is seen. Some gets elevation values(correct values), the others have null values.
  Neither the toolbox nor the Arcpy script throw any error.
- We noticed ,using one raster(Geotiffs on disk) at a time is giving us correct values. This is however taking 12 hours or more - not suitable for task at hand.

Comment: Do the extracted points have the correct elevations? You could also try building a virtual raster instead of/over the mosaic. I don't see how that would help but it's easy to test.

Comment: What are the precise steps that you perform, beginning with when you start ArcMap, when you see this failure?  For any tools used what are the parameter values?

Comment: Check your environment extent.

Comment: Does 18 lakh = 1,800,000?

Comment: I wondered what a [lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) was too.

Comment: @PolyGeo updated my query per your comments

Comment: What happens when you run this on some subsets of the same data e.g. 1,000,000 points, 100,000 points and 10,000 points?

Comment: I don't believe you answered the question: are the subset of points returned actually correct? (Or were you saying they're *only* correct when you use "one raster"?)

Comment: @PolyGeo , For a subset wherever I am getting elevation values,they are correct. For single raster , all elevation values are extracted correctly and no nulls seen unless DEM itself got nulls.

Comment: You say "When we experimented with subset say - 600 points or 20,000 points - the same issue is seen" so let's forget about working with 1.8 million points for now and see if you still see it with 1, 10 and 100 points.

Comment: Did not matter. The tool simply does not work the way it is claimed in documentation. Ironic that end user is Tester for ESRI. I am finding a work around and will answer it once I am sure about it.